# Cannot run a script as root with systemctl

Tags: linux, bluetooth, debian, systemd

I need to apply a patch ram to a chip for Bluetooth on startup of a Debian linux. This patch uses `/dev/mem` to reset the GPIO. This updated init script for bluetooth is included in `/etc/init.d/bluetooth`.

My `bluetooth.service` is

```
[Unit]
Description=Bluetooth service
Documentation=man:bluetoothd(8)

[Service]
Type=dbus
BusName=org.bluez
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/bluetooth start
User=root
NotifyAccess=main

[Install]
WantedBy=bluetooth.target
Alias=dbus-org.bluez.service
```

However, when I reboot, I get an error saying `Unable to open /dev/mem: Operation not permitted"

I understand that `/dev/mem` is only accessible to root, but aren't I running my init script as root?

Answer (score -4):

It clearly says that you don't have permission to run a script, you can
you need to run the script as root user as
`ExecStart=/etc/init.d/bluetooth start`
this command should be run as root user

just login as root and re-run the script

**Running the script when system startup**

1. Create a script called bluetooth.service in /etc/init.d/ directory(login as root)
   `vi /etc/init.d/bluetooth.service`
2. Setup executable permission on script:
   `chmod +x /etc/init.d/bluetooth.service`
3. Make sure this script get executed every time Debian Linux system boot up/comes up:

   `update-rc.d bluetooth.service defaults 100`

Where, bluetooth.service:  is Your startup script name
defaults : The argument 'defaults' refers to the default runlevels, which are 2 through 5.
100 : Number 100 means script will get executed before any script containing number 101.
Just run the command

```
ls –l /etc/rc3.d/
```

This command will soft linked to /etc/init.d with numbers.

Next time you reboot the system, you custom command or script will get executed via bluetooth.services. Y

4. Execute shell script at system startup
   Open the file bluetooth.service in /etc/init.d/ directory

Comment: I understand what the problem is. This is an init script. I don't want to manually run this script. I want it to run atomically when the system boots up.

Comment: I have added details about the system start up

Comment: I'll test this later tomorrow. With `systemctl` I thought you include the service inside `/lib/systemd/system/` and then have the `ExecStatr` link to whatever file you want. What you have provided seems like a SysVInit method

Comment: If you want the service to be started on boot up, you need to run `sudo systemctl enable bluetooth.service`